# Plotting an inequality over the range of a parameter

Tags: plotting, inequalities, parameters

I have a simple inequality, $$x+\cos(\theta)\, y > 0$$ and I'd like to plot the region in $x,y$ space which satisfies this inequality for all values of the angle $\theta$. I'm trying to do this with RegionPlot,

```
RegionPlot[AllTrue[x + Cos[\[Theta]] y > 0, Positive], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

But this returns an empty plot. The final result should be a plot of $x>|y|$. Could anyone help me with implementing this in Mathematica?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We set `t=Cos[θ]`.

```
FunctionRange[Cos[θ], θ, t]
```

> `-1 <= t <= 1`.

```
cond = ForAll[t, -1 <= t <= 1, x + t*y > 0];
result = Resolve[cond, Reals];
(* reg=ImplicitRegion[result,{x,y}]; *)
RegionPlot[result, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
sol = Select[Reduce[x + y Cos[θ] > 0, θ, Reals], 
  FreeQ[#, θ] &]
```

> x > 0 && -x < y < x

```
Region[
 ImplicitRegion[sol, {x, y}]
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}
 ]
```

[image]